# Use of gizmo exits Lock Camera to View

Tags: 3d-view

Whenever I Lock Camera to View and then attempt to navigate using the 3D gizmo, the view is immediately no longer locked to the camera.

Is there a way to allow the use of the gizmo while keeping the view locked to the camera?

Sorry if, as usual, I am unclear...

In response to Answer 1 below:

The first image shows that in Lock Camera to View mode, I can see the gizmo.

The second image shows the view after clicking the gizmo, which reflects the view no longer being locked to camera view.

If I am able to manipulate the view "inside the camera view", why can't I use the gizmo to do so?

Also, I am not trying to navigate the camera. I am trying to use the gizmo to navigate the model view, while maintaining the Locked Camera to View.

[image: View through locked camera view]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean? You can't navigate the camera with gizmos if you are viewing through that camera. The Gizmo wouldn't even be visible. Could you show us a screenshot?

Update: You must be hitting the heads or the axis. You are supposed to grab around them. Clicking on the axes will send you to that view and out of camera mode

If you want to use those with the camera you would have to move the camera each time to those new locations. There is a shortcut where the camera moves to see what you are seeing in the viewport. Hold CTRL and ALT and Zero on the number pad.

Comment: With the camera locked to the view, I am free to manually move my view around, and were I end up as viewed by the camera is the camera view. Why does it make a difference whether I move the view around with the mouse or the gizmo? I'm familiar with the CTRL-ALT-ZERO, which is how I'm setting up the camera view. Why, when I select the gizmo to look in the Y direction (for example), does the camera view not show the Y direction view? Instead it exits, and returns to the workspace. To view directly along an axis requires selection of the "dot" on the gizmo. That's what I'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: Let's try this from a different approach: with the camera locked to the view, how is one supposed to achieve a view looking normal to an axis, if one is unable to select the gizmo? That is my requirement.

Comment: @Rocket Hello :). One way is to get the desired view, and then *align active camera to view*.

Comment: @RocketSurgeon I am not sure what you mean. If you are aware of how to snap the camera to view then what exactly is your problem? Unless you are saying that you want to view with the same perspective. If that's what you mean, press 5 on your number pad when you click on an axis and it will throw you back in orthographic view, which is what the gizmo sets you in. This is mean to be so that you can line things up from the sides